# How to generate several DIV blocks in array like manner?

Tags: javascript

How can I use JavaScript to generate multiple DIV blocks with IDs in them, where IDs are given, say by another variable, and are not sequential.  For example:

```
<div id="x_y_curve_123" class="graph"></div>
<div id="x_y_curve_256" class="graph"></div>
...
<div id="x_y_curve_354" class="graph"></div>
```

Comment: Could you use data attributes to store the IDs?

Comment: I'm afraid not ... flot uses Div Ids to draw its stuff.  Maybe, if flot can be modified, but can't modify it directly, as it's a library.  so btw, I split my question into parts & simplified this one, as what I was asking was not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do it. You can do it like this:

Consider you are going add 10 divs inside a div with id="myDivs", then

```
for(var i=1; i<11; i++){
    $("#myDivs").append('<div id="x_y_curve_'+i+'" class="graph"></div>');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly you are looking for, but an easy way to generate rows of divs is something like this.

```
for(y=2;y>-3;y--) {
    if(y == 0) y--;
    for(x=-2;x<3;x++) {
        if(x == 0) x++;
        $('body').append('<div id="x_y_curve_'+x+'_'+y+'" style="border:1px solid black;width:100px;height:100px;float:left" data-x='+x+' data-y='+y+'></div>');
    }
    $('body').append('<div style="line-height:102px"><br></div>');
}
```

If you do it this way, each div will have a specific x and y coordinate, which might make it easier for processing it.

http://jsfiddle.net/dqqkr7rh/